# Reliable File transfer from Django to external FTP

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ftp

I have a Django application that needs to upload files generated upon the update of a model objects. More concretely, once a database entry is modified, a function has to be fired to generate a tiny CSV file and upload it to an (S)FTP server. My question is on how to make the uploads reliable and performant (possibly couple of thousands transactions a day). That is, make sure the files are always uploaded with possibly few duplicates without overloading the Django instance.
One option I explored was to send these tiny CSV files to a cloud queue (e.g. AWS SNS/SQS) and have another CRON job (e.g. AWS Lambda) to fetch the queue and upload the files.
Any ideias for the architecture?